# Wait after Docker Compose cluster is up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using Docker Compose for integration tests. After starting a cluster with Docker Compose I need to wait for some time until the application and its cache is up. I see ways to make one container wait before starting another but is there a way to make the whole set up wait?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, some process run automocally and you want to wait before run these processes?

Comment: @Kilian basically, I would like to wait until the app is up so that I could run tests

Comment: Had the same issue, especially with database, there are unusable for some time with weird app errors, and finally end up with endly (https://github.com/viant/endly/), to mange my docker database workflow, which does active check with various driver or REST api if docker app/service is ready

Answer (score 3):

You need to work out what you mean by the "cluster is up". Docker doesn't really care too much about what the application inside each container is doing, so long as it doesn't terminate.

If you need to wait for some state transitions *inside* the containers, you'll need to manage this at the application level - for instance, you could write to a file on a filesystem exposed from the container, you could HTTP POST a message somewhere, etc, etc. Then pick up that message and use that to start your integration test. I'd strongly consider reusing whatever you're using for your monitoring infrastructure, as this is effectively the same problem.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you! but there are certain checks that allow be to ensure the app is up. so I would like to check certain url in a loop, I have it in our Jenkins pipelines, but I would like to integrate it somehow in docker compose itself